# pod install resets simulator/device setting in XCode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, ios-simulator

I normally have my XCode use my device (Iphone SE) to run my app on.

Everytime i install a pod file, the setting is switched back to iphone 8 Simulator.

Is there anyway I can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have selected iPhone 8 as default simulator device. Once pods are installed it resets to the default state

Try changing the default simulator device